# Using xpath on chrome return duplicate element id when there is only one

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

i try to search a element with xpath on the console via chrome and it always return me 2 elements but in my html i have only one element with that id.
Here my xpath i type in console.

```
$x("//div[@id='vd-img-startVideo']")
```

not sure why it always duplicate that value in the console someone know the reason did my xpath wrong??

Comment: What's the explicit return value? In other words, why do you think it's returning two, and how are you sure there's only one element with that id?

Comment: it return array of 2 and pretty sure it has one element i have the html code i did a search on the page with my IDE and even scan each id don't know if it relate to angular because search over a id in stackoverflow return only 1 element kind confuse

Comment: Source and Dom are two different things-only the dom is an accurate representation of the current state of the page.